# Using functions from .js file in .ejs file

Tags: javascript, ejs, client-side

I have a .ejs file from which I am trying to access a function from a .js file. Both of these contain client-side code. My problem is, when I try to call the function from the .ejs file, the function cannot be found because the .js does not get used.

I have a link to the .js file in the .ejs file's  tag.

Could someone help me with this problem as I am quite new to Javascript?

.ejs file content:

```
...
<button type="button" onclick="overlayOn()">view comment</button>
```

.js file has a function called overlayOn()

```
function overlayOn() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
  }
```

The error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: overlayOn is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Comment: Where did you attach your js file to html code?

Comment: Sorry this was a msitake. I linked the .js file in the .ejs file <script> tag. I don't have a separate HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by using the following line:

```
app.use("/public", express.static('public'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wrap all your event functions inside a document load function. 
From https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event :

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

If the DOM loads after your script files run, then they are targeting something that hasn't loaded yet. As an added precaution, place your script tags at the bottom of your body element so it runs after the rest of the page has loaded. Hope this works!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to make a difference. The .js file does not appear in the 'sources' tab of the developer tools.

Comment: can you show the full ejs file? It would be useful to see where things are. Did you double check the file path on the script tag is correct?